Why is power good used like this in this application?
My understanding is that power good signal is normally used to pull down the reset pin of the main microcontroller when you have a power issue like overcurrent or any other power problem with the regulator.
But in the
TPS563257 datasheet there is a link to webench tool. In the suggested layout there is a resistor "Rpg" to Vout. What is the advantage of doing this?
the Vout would just be pulled to ground when Power Good is activated... And that would happen sooner or later anyway is power is being turned off..  or am I missing something?


PG on this one is open drain, meaning that you need a pull-up somewhere to make it work. If your downstream IC has internal current source for enable, job done. If not and you need logic voltage level, you need a resistor.
If you don’t want Vout level but something else to fit your logic, connect the resistor to that rail instead.

OK, So after reading the different answer my understanding is that the PG is to make "remove" the charge from regulator output when there is a fault to get to an logic offstate (around 0 volt) and not be undefined (between Vout and 0V). Or to use with a reset on another circuit.
And the resistor is there to so the PG do not make the sinking of the signal to "strong". My understanding is also the voltage regulator would still work without PG being used. But then you risk a output undefined state if you have fault. correct?

@mrdude Yes. If you don’t need the PG signal, feel free to ignore it. Most probably you can leave it floating but check the datasheet to make sure.

The PG is an open-drain output.
The pin can only pull low when power is not OK (and there is enough input supply for the PG signal to work).
So the resistor is required to pull the PG signal high when power is OK.
Without the resistor the signal would just float at some indeterminate voltage. Unless you use a MCU with internal pull-up resistor on the pin.
The resistor can be pulled up to some other voltage too that is present but then the regulator cannot output PG if it is unpowered.
So if you want to use the regulator output for powering some chip, you can use the PG signal as reset for that chip so it gets unreset after power is stabilized.

OK, So after reading the different answer my understanding is that the PG is to make "remove" the charge from regulator output when there is a fault to get to an logic offstate (around 0 volt) and not be undefined (between Vout and 0V). Or to use with a reset on another circuit.
And the resistor is there to so the PG do not make the sinking of the signal to "strong". My understanding is also the voltage regulator would still work without PG being used. But then you risk a output undefined state if you have fault. correct?

@mrdude The PG is not necessarily used to discharge the voltage from regulator output. It will do that of course but very slowly and only if pulled up to it's own output. The main purpose is to give a logic signal when power is good or not good. I do not see other answers saying it is used to discharge the output, what makes you think so?

Then why would the manufacturer in their example design (my first image) show it being connected directly to Vout? I understand the point with connecting it to the reset of the MCU. But why connect to Vout if you have no MCU? (like in first image). Because it should be posible to just leave unconnected for this regulator is my understanding.

@mrdude If you intend to use it, the Vout is usually the only voltage you have available so you connect it there. The examples are examples how to use all features of the chip. If you know you will not use the feature then you can read the data sheet how to not use some feature. Usually it might be simplest for test and prototyping to use a pull-up so you can verify the regulator operation. In production you can ignore it, remove pull up and leave pin floating, or wire it to ground - whichever is the recommended way to not use the feature.

OK, I understand now why. Thank you so much for your explanation and help!


Vout would just be pulled to ground when Power Good is activated... And that would happen sooner or later anyway is power is being turned off.. or am I missing something?

Well, during this failure event, you cannot be sure it results in 0V on Vout. If you for example have a 3.3V regulator, it could potentially be loaded in such a way that it outputs only 2.5V which may be enough to somewhat power your MCU, but outside of its specified supply voltage range which may cause it to do however crazy things.
So you can use the PG signal to make sure you keep the MCU in reset during this time.
Even the digital world is in some ways, still always analog.

OK, So after reading the different answer my understanding is that the PG is to make "remove" the charge from regulator output when there is a fault to get to an logic offstate (around 0 volt) and not be undefined (between Vout and 0V). Or to use with a reset on another circuit.
And the resistor is there to so the PG do not make the sinking of the signal to "strong". My understanding is also the voltage regulator would still work without PG being used. But then you risk a output undefined state if you have fault. correct?

The PG pin indicates if the FB pin is within ±15%.  The output is open drain, so it requires a pullup resistor.  The pullup would typically be several kiloohms.  So, its not going to pull down the output or anything.
Note that even if the supply output is outside the ±15% window, that doesn't mean its zero.  It's perfectly valid to connect the pullup resistor to the supply output.  In many cases this is necessary if the PG pin connects to something being powered by the supply.
For example, if PG connects to the reset line of a microcontroller being powered by that supply, then you don't want to pull the reset line (or any other IO) higher than the supply voltage.

OK, So after reading the different answer my understanding is that the PG is to make "remove" the charge from regulator output when there is a fault to get to an logic offstate (around 0 volt) and not be undefined (between Vout and 0V). Or to use with a reset on another circuit.
And the resistor is there to so the PG do not make the sinking of the signal to "strong". My understanding is also the voltage regulator would still work without PG being used. But then you risk a output undefined state if you have fault. correct?
